# c++ friend методы

Tags: c++

Я хочу открыть методу класса **B** полный доступ к приватным членам класса **A**, но получаю от компилятора непонятное сообщение об ошибке.

Вот упрощенный пример кода:

```
class A;
class B;

class A
{
    friend void B::execute(A &_a);
    public:
    // ...
    private:
    // ...
};

class B
{
    void execute(A &_a);
};
```

Сообщение компилятора:

```
error: invalid use of incomplete type 'class A::B'|
```

Как я понял, компилятор принимает **B::execute()** за **A::B::execute()**? Как ему объяснить, что я от него хочу?

Comment: Вы что-то выдумываете. В таком коде не будет сообщения про `class A::B`. Вы привели непоказательный код. Скорее всего в реальности у вас `class B;` сидело внутри `A`.

Comment: @AnT, нет. Я уже понял, в чем проблема, объявлять метод дружественным можно только после полного объявления класса, где этот метод находится.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нет, компилятор просто не понимает, о каком таком

```
void B::execute(A &_a);
```

вы ему рассказываете - в этот момент он понятия не имеет, что именно есть в `B`, в частности, метод `execute()`....

Вот так вполне работает:

```
class A;
class B
{
public:
    void execute(A &_a);
};


class A
{
    friend void B::execute(A &_a);
    public:
    // ...
    private:
    // ...
};
```

Comment: Это единственный способ решить проблему? Это решение годится только для простого случая. В случае, если у классов **A** и **B** есть дружественные друг другу методы, проблема неразрешима?

Comment: @Максим, если у `A` и `B` есть дружественные друг другу методы, то это уже проблема дизайна. Решения есть и другие, но все через дополнительные функции/классы.

Comment: @ixSci, я понял, спасибо.

Comment: Просто если классов много, и *некоторые* методы *некоторых* классов должны иметь доступ к приватным частям друг друга, то все становится очень плохо.

Comment: @Максим, тогда нужно подумать, а может нужно как-то переделать классы? Может стоит часть какого-то функционала вынести в третий класс? Может что-то нужно сделать публичным? Вариантов масса может быть; использовать `friend` —  последнее дело.

Comment: @ixSci, когда я изначально весь проект реализовал на **C**, там вообще не было таких проблем. А вот в плюсах прямо на каждом шагу какие-то костыли нужны. Сейчас я хотел использовать **friend** для того, чтобы **точечно** нарушить инкапсуляцию. Но в итоге весь проект превтатится в один большой костыль, потому что компилятору нужно видеть полные определения классов. Эх, боль.

Comment: @Максим, просто Вы, вероятно, попали в ловушку, в которую попадают многие программисты, переходящие с одного языка на другой. Они начинают писать на старом языке синтаксисом нового. Это неправильно. Набьёте шишек и поймёте как делать правильно, со временем. Если есть желание ускорить процесс, тогда рекомендую почитать книги по дизайну приложений в ООП стиле. Их достаточно.

Comment: @ixSci, спасибо, видимо так и придется этим заняться)